# How to render n flex-cards into a service console

Tags: service-cloud-console, omnistudio

Once upon a time, Vlocity flex-cards could be presented in a console UI where if a customer had say 1 open case and 3 mobile phone plans, then you could dynamically present 4 flex-cards into the console - 1 for the case and 3 for each of the plans. See screenshot attached. Trying to recall how to achieve that within configured capabilities - do I need to build an LWC to run the queries against case and 'plan', then loop through them to render , or is this a container of some sort that we pass queries into and it manages the rendering trying to figure out where to start. Any pointers most appreciated!

[image: old vlocity screenshot]